# attaching file in mail using sendgrid api salesforce..?

Tags: api, salesforce, send, sendgrid

I am having problem attaching file to a mail using sendgrid API. I am successful sending mails.

How can I use the attached file API? How can I use form data content deposition?

```
                 string url,burl;
                 burl='https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json';              //?api_user='+apiuser+'&api_key='+apikey;
url='api_user='+encodingutil.urlEncode(apiuser,'UTF-8')+'&api_key='+encodingutil.urlEncode(apikey,'UTF-8');

                if(mails.toname!=null && mails.toname!='')
                {
                url+='&toname='+encodingutil.urlEncode(mails.toname,'UTF-8');
                }

                if(mails.subject!=null && mails.subject!='')
                {
                url+='&subject='+encodingutil.urlEncode(mails.subject,'UTF-8');
                }
                if(mails.text!=null && mails.text!='')
                {
                url+='&text='+encodingutil.urlEncode(mails.text,'UTF-8');
                }  

                //url+='&html='+mails.html;  

              ****Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[myfile]"; filename="myfile"****

                http h=new http();
                Httprequest req=new Httprequest();
                Httpresponse res=new Httpresponse();
                req.setEndpoint(burl);
                req.setBody(url);
                req.setMethod('GET');  
                res=h.send(req);
                    response=res.getBody();
                    if(response.contains('success'))
                    {
                        response='{"message":"success"}';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response='Error: '+res.getBody();
                    }
```